# Which cab should I deploy to my handheld device to install CF version 2?

Tags: arm, compact-framework, windows-ce, motorola, handhelddevice

Based on what I read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb788171%28v=vs.90%29.aspx#Explorer), in order to install CF version 2 on my handheld device, I should copy over one of the cab files here:

[image]

...but which one?

The device in question is a Symbol 3090, which currently has only CF version 1.0.3316.00 (1.0 SP2) installed. The OS version of the device is 05.00.1400

The device CPU is presumably 'ARMV4I' as a similar device (Motorola 3190) says that it is equipped with such.

### UPDATE

Based on what I see [here](http://kb.digitalscout.com/index.php?action=artikel&cat=1&id=7550&artlang=en) when I click "this link" here:

*-- OR -- If you have Windows Mobile 5 or newer on your device, click this link and save the file to the desktop of your computer.*

...it seems "*NETCFv2.wm.armv4i.cab*" is probably the best choice.

Any refutations?

### UPDATE 2

I copied the file I reckoned to be the one, and clicked it on the device, but:

[image]

What in Sam L. Clemens' illustrious memory is going on here?!?

### UPDATE 3

I then copied over the other file from the link above, which was slightly different (2.12MB as opposed to 2.14MB, for one thing), and tried to run it, and got the same err msg as above.

### UPDATE 4

Trying to install from the last link, I see:

[image]

### UPDATE 5

Actually, it turns out that what I might really need is to install CF version 1 after a cold boot of the device...but I don't know if version 1 of CF is still available. That's the only version the existing .exe will run on, but my PC only has cab files for versions 2 and 3.5...???

### UPDATE 6

In the most recent version of the .exe (builds and compiles, but won't run on either device), it has three, count 'em three mscorlibs in its References area; the versions are:

```
1.0.5000.0
2.0.0.0
3.5.0.0
```

They all have the same public key token (the same as shown in the screen shot)

The only other multi-reference is System, which has both version 2 and 3.5

AND, below System.Xml, there are three coredll.dlls, albeit spelled differently:

```
coredll.dll
CoreDll.dll
CoreDll.DLL
```

(no info for any of them...???)

### UPDATE 7

I copied NETCFv2.wce4.ARMV4.cab to the 3090.

I 2-clicked it on the device, but got this:

[image]

And so, I retreated (selected "No").

Thus continue unabated the travails of an accidental handheld developer.

### UPDATE 8

The project is set to Framework Version == v2.0, Platform == Windows CE, Target Device == Windows Mobile 6 Classic Emulator (one of the few emulator choices I have), and the output shows that it *is* ARMV4i that is being deployed:

```
Deploying '%CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILES%\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\v3.5\Devices\wce500\ARMV4i    
\sqlce.ppc.wce5.armv4i.CAB'

Deploying '%CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILES%\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\v3.5\Devices\wce500\ARMV4i    
\sqlce.repl.ppc.wce5.armv4i.CAB'

Deploying '%CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILES%\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\v3.5\Devices\wce500\ARMV4i    
\sqlce.dev.enu.ppc.wce5.armv4i.CAB'

Deploying 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Motorola EMDK for .NET\v2.8\SDK\Smart Devices\wce500\armv4i\symbol.all.arm.cab'
```

And when I run the .exe in the emulator, it fails with, "*Error - An unexpected error has occurred in Platypus.exe
Select Quit and restart this program, or select Details for more information.
This application requires a newer version of the MS .NET Compact Framework than the version installed on this device*."

Selecting the "Details" button augments the mental anguish with, "*TypeLoadException
This application requires a newer version of the MS .NET Compact Framework than the version installed on this device.*"

Comment: Both of those devices are ARMv4 (not 4i).

Comment: In \wce400, there are two "armv4" cab files: NETCFv2.ppc.armv4.cab and NETCFv2.wce4.ARMV4.cab
In \wce500, there are two "armv4i" cab files (the two I tried to install). So you're saying one of the first two should be (presumably the latter - NETCFv2.wce4.ARMV4.cab) should be what I  copy over to the OS 05 device?

Comment: Either is likely to work, but if your devices are not Pocket PC, use the "wce" version.

Comment: Don't let the KGB know about this effective method in how to drive a body insane in several brain-wrenching steps (by forcing them to unravel and align this macabre versioning minutiae).

Comment: Actually, I'm not overly hopeful of the new version of the app running on the older device, even when updated with a version 2 cab file, as the other device already has version 2 (and 3.5) and it doesn't run on that one...

Comment: @ctacke: Make that an answer, and I'll mark it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your are using the WinCE 4.2 version of the 3090 (it comes in 4.2 and 5.0), you should proceed with the install using `NETCFv2.wce4.ARMV4.cab`.  "The program is not compatible..." message is a warning only, and not a very smart one.  There is even a way to edit the cab to remove that warning if you wanted to, though my memory fails me on the exact way to do it.  I've had to do it to allow a silent install before (otherwise the nag screen gets in your way).

Comment: It is WinCE 5; so that means I should *not* install using NETCFv2.wce4.ARMV4.cab?
"CE Version 5.00 (Build 1400)"

Comment: Then you should be using `NETCFv2.wce5.ARMV4i.cab`

Comment: I tried that, and it failed; also, I'm pretty sure The CF Whisperer (ctacke) advised against it.

Comment: Our product used CF2 SP1 on the MC3090 for years and it worked just fine.  I don't even recall installing it being an issue.  CF3.5 works great on them as well, BTW.  I'll have to re-read your question because, to be honest, I tuned out after like the third sequel to update 2 ;)

Comment: Previous versions of the .exe have run fine on both devices, too; it is a problem with this latest .exe that I'm trying to track down - what has changed? Why? How?

Comment: Well your question was which cab to install.  My assumption is that the "not working" has to do with your application and that should go in a separate question, unless a simple app also fails on the version of cab you selected.

Comment: It is the attempted installation of the cab itself that fails - nothing to do with my app. There are, indeed, many questions in the past few days specifically about this app, though.

Comment: Sorry, the "Error - An unexpected error has occurred in Platypus.exe" stuff through me off.  So you are getting "not a valid Windows CE Setup" when installing the `NETCFv2.wce5.ARMV4i.cab`?

Comment: I don't recall now exactly what the error was, but it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to figure out what version of CE you are running. You can find this by going to System Properties. Also while you are in System Properties note what processor you are running ( arm, mips ...). If you are running windows ce 4.2 or higher you will pick a cab file out of the wce400 folder. If you are running windows CE 5.0 or higher you will pick a cab file out of the wce500 folder. Note you can't install .net 2.0 on windows ce 4.1 or lower, according to Microsoft documentation, however, I have noticed that the minimum version setting on the cab files is 4.0, so you might be able to hack it. 
Like I said before on also the System Properties page is the type of processor you are using. From that select the appropriate sub-folder in either wce400 or wce500. In most of the folders for each processor there should be only one cab file. If there is more than one cab file see if the file name contains wm for windows mobile, wce for windows ce, or ppc for pocket PC and pick the one most appropriate for you.

You can also take the guess work out of this whole process by creating an ini file with the fallowing text and using ceappmgn.exe to pick and install the right cab file for you.

```
[CEAppManager]
Version = 1.0
Component = NETCF

[NETCF]
Description = .NET Compact Framework v2.0
CabFiles=wce400\armv4\NETCFv2.ppc.armv4.cab,wce400\armv4\NETCFv2.wce4.ARMV4.cab,wce400\mipsii\NETCFv2.wce4.MIPSII.cab,wce400\mipsiv\NETCFv2.wce4.MIPSIV.cab,wce400\sh4\NETCFv2.wce4.sh4.cab,wce400\x86\NETCFv2.wce4.x86.cab,wce500\armv4i\NETCFv2.wm.armv4i.cab,wce500\mipsii\NETCFv2.wce5.mipsii.cab,wce500\mipsiv\NETCFv2.wce5.mipsiv.cab,wce500\sh4\NETCFv2.wce5.sh4.cab,wce500\armv4i\NETCFv2.wce5.armv4i.cab
```

Comment: "You can find this by going to System Properties."
If you mean System Info, I see, on the System tab, "OS Version: 0.6.00.0000"
In "System" I see "MS Windows CE Version 6.00"
"System Info > Config Info" shows shows "MC3100 WCE Pr..." for "Platform"

Comment: IOW, I already figured out that I need an armv4.cab file from the wce500 folder, but which one of the two that are there, was the question

Comment: because you are installing on a Windows CE device I would go with NETCFv2.wce5.armv4i.cab

Comment: Thanks, but as mentioned above, both attempts fail with an err msg about them not being valid files.

Comment: try [this](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22808) installer from microsoft. It will use ActiveSync or MSDC and will pick the right CAB for you.

Comment: also I notice above you were using NETCFv2.wm.armv5i.cab. As I mentioned in my answer above the wm in the file name stands for Windows Mobile and you aree using Windows CE so you want NETCFv2.wce5.armv4i.cab where wce5 stands for Windows CE 5.0.

Comment: Yes, in Update 3, I mention that after the first one failed, I tried the other one, and it too failed. I see now that the verbiage was unclear, so I clarified that.

Comment: New related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23505211/which-sqlserverce-dll-version-do-i-need-to-reference-in-my-project-to-match-what